# How to stop administrator password prompt on application install (OSX)

Tags: macos, administration

How to turn off administrator password prompt on application install or other actions on mac?

I tried to put line in `/etc/sudoers` file:

`zur4ik ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

where `zur4ik` is my username.

unfortunately it's not working: applications are asking for administrators password anyway.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a huge security hole?

Comment: yes it will be, but I'm hesitated by asking password every time. 
Even if I want to rename folder, it's asking passord.

Comment: Most of this is controlled by the rules in /etc/authorization; you can edit that if you want, but it's more likely you'll break things completely than accomplish what you want.

Comment: Question is opened too long time and answer was given in comment. As far as no one answered as "Answer" I can mark question as `Solved` so please close it as already answered question. 

Thanks in advance.